# Listen to model value change and calculate

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a template where width and height are writable, area is calculated:

```
width [___] x height [___] = area [___]
```

Right now both width and height have a listener something like:

```
<input (ngModelChange)="updateValues()"...>

## component

public updateValues(): void {
    this.model.area = this.model.width * this.model.height;
}
```

Problem with this approach is that when form gets more complex then each argument needs to call calculation of the formulas they are part of, e.g:

```
public updateValues(): void {
    this.model.area = this.model.width * this.model.height;
    this.model.calculatable1 = ...;
    this.model.calculatable2 = ...;
    this.model.calculatable3 = ...;
}
```

This should not be arguments responsibility but results'. This has already gotten out of hands.

So I would like to refuct this so that calculation of a results is encapsuled in a single class with argument value listeners. Something along these lines:

```
class AreaCalculator {
    public constructor(model) {
        model.width.onchange = function() {
            model.area = this.calculate(model.width, model.height);
        }
        model.height.onchange = function() {
            model.area = this.calculate(model.width, model.height);
        }
    }

    public calculate(width, height) {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

I played with idea to make width and height into Observables but in my model width and height are declared as numbers and I would like to keep it that way.

Then there is an option to use setInterval but I'm sure there are more elegant ways out there.

Comment: why dont you create a service with a single calculate method then call it in your component

Comment: The problem was not calculation itself but where to set up listeners. I dont want them into template.

Comment: So did u solve it? A suggestion (i guess) could be to use ReactiveForms where you can subscribe to FormControll change events instead of having to setup change event bindings in the view

Comment: Then you can update calculator model and pass it to a service which calculates the result and updates your view or whatever